# Array sort function without any argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, functional-programming

Can anybody explain how in this case sort works?

```
var arrayNumb = [2, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];
arrayNumb.sort();
console.log(arrayNumb); // [ 15, 16, 2, 23, 42, 8 ]
```

Comment: it's treating the values as strings.

Comment: Don't you see it's a lexical sort? eg. 15 comes after 1, but before 2 because the first char in 15 is lower than the first char in 2.. Most OS-es sort files like this even when the files are numeric names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> compareFunction Optional
>   Specifies a function that defines the sort order. **If omitted, the array is sorted according to each character's Unicode code point value, according to the string conversion of each element.**